# Find the minima

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x}$

My first instict was to simplify $x^3/x$ to $x^2$. However this gives me incorrect answer with minima being $0$. I assume that the simplification I did was incorrect. I am wondering why the simplification was incorrect?

Is it because the domain of the function has changed?

Comment: Yes, you changed the domain. Actually $f$ has no minimum. It has an infimum, though, which is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_1(x)=\frac{x^3}{x}$ and $f_2(x)=x^2$ are the same up to the domain. The second function can be defined for every real $x$, whereas the first one cannot take $x=0$, because of the division by 0.